# How to display a GUI Texture for a certain amount of time

Tags: unity, gui, timer

Is it possible to make a gui Texture display for a certain amount of Time.

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching the following class to the `GameObject` containing your `GUITexture`. The texture should have gone hidden 3 seconds after being activated.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(GUITexture))]
public class GUITestClass : MonoBehaviour {
    GUITexture gt;

    void Awake() {
        gt = GetComponent<GUITexture>();
    }

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine("HideGt");
    }

    IEnumerator HideGt() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        gt.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the coroutine?

Comment: Surely this is just one of the many different ways to solve the case.

Comment: Using a threaded coroutine to simply wait 3 seconds seems overkill.

Comment: @Blue I disagree, this is a great way to deal with the problem. Using CRs is a very efficient and clean way to do things in general. It may be over kill in certain cases but what if you also wanted to play a sound when the texture is hidden? Now you have two things to do on the same 'event'. That single line Destroy now becomes useless. With a CR on the other hand you will have no headaches.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one line of code:

```
Destroy(gameObject, 3);
```

This will destroy the object after three seconds.

Put this in your script after you have sorted out your text and GUI related stuff and you're sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class scene9 : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public Texture2D startWin;
    public Texture2D setupWin;

    private bool startwindow = true;
    private bool setupWindow = false;
    void Start () {
        Invoke ("startwindowFun", 2);
        Invoke ("setupwindowFun",3);
        Invoke ("loadScene11",5);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    public void startwindowFun() {
        startwindow = !setupWindow;
        }
    public void setupwindowFun() {
        startwindow = setupWindow;
        setupWindow = !setupWindow;
    }
    public void loadScene11() {
        Application.LoadLevel ("Scene11");
    }

    void OnGUI() {

                if (startwindow) {
                        GUI.Label (new Rect (270, 300, 160, 100), startWin); 


                }

                if (setupWindow) {
                        GUI.Label (new Rect (270, 300, 300, 100), setupWin);

                }

        }   

}
```

The above code works to load a texture one after the another at a specified time.It worked for me.